# Eclipse Compiler Compliance Level Not Affecting Additional Class Files

Tags: java, eclipse

The JRE of my Eclipse project is a version of Java 17, but I added class files that were compiled in Java 13. I tried setting the compiler compliance level to Java 8 because that's the lowest version I want my project to run on, but using any Java version below the one that the class files were compiled in results in an error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Customer has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 57.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at TollwayCustomerDataBase.main(TollwayCustomerDataBase.java:19)
```

Is there a way I can change the version the class files were compiled in? Or any other solutions so that my project would run on Java 8? (I do not have access to the source code of the class files).

Comment: Sometimes cleaning and rebuilding project helps.

Comment: There is no way to change the version the class files were compiled in other than to recompile them to the intended level. Each new version adds new features and sections to the class file layout, meaning you can't metaphorically file off the version number and proceed.